# Bundling not working when deployed to azure asp mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have css files and js files, locally link are rendered in the head as expected but on azure the links are not rendered at all, why?

I have looked through various threads and most seem to point towards there being an issue with naming the bundle name the same as the file path, both are different. Others have said that `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />` should be 
 `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />` and others have said to try            `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`
 in the Bundle.config. Non have worked for me, can someone please point me in the right direction

my bundles are

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/styles").Include(
                    "~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "etc...",
                    "~/assets/css/theme.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/scripts").Include(
                    "~/assets/js/filter.js",
                    "etc...",
                    "~/assets/js/ContactForm.js"));
```

my folder structure is

```
assets/css
assets/js
```

in my _Layout.cshtml they are called

```
@Styles.Render("~/assets/styles")
@Scripts.Render("~/assets/scripts")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the `assets` folder already existing. Have you tried just using `~/styles` and `~/scripts`?

The assumption you've made is that because the `assets/styles` folder doesn't exist a virtual path will be created. The issue is more likely to do with Azure discovering the Directory `assets` and treating everything within it as actual resources, skipping past the point of creating a virtual path. If I were you, I wouldn't bother with trying to make it work, at best you'll have what you wanted but really, at worst, you'll have wasted hours on a matter that makes no business sense and adds no real value to the UX...